# Chrome extension WebNavigation listener for hash change

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been using `chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted` and `onCompleted` listeners successfully to detect page changes, but now there are some websites that loads new pages entirely with just URL hash part changed.
And those changes don't fire these two listeners.
Is there any way to instruct chrome.webNavigation API to listen to these changes in URL as well? Or is there any other method in Chrome extension to do it?

Comment: can you provide an example of just the URL hash part changing?

Comment: u doubt those cause navigation as are client only. you might need to use tabs or content script to periodically check

Comment: Some related questions have been answered by using [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) in a content script. This handles ajax requests and DOM changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) - for **all** URL changes, needs `"permissions": ["tabs"]` in manifest

  ```js
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
      if (changeInfo.url) {
          console.log('Tab %d got new URL: %s', tabId, changeInfo.url);
      }
  });
  ```
- [chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) - for changes made via [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/history)

See also: [JS methods of detecting page changes available in a content script.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated is just what I needed. The other event is not triggered, guess the page doesn't use history api. Thanks for nicely formatted log line!

Comment: @wOxxOm isn't it possible to do this with webNavigation?

Comment: Direct hash changes via assigning `location.href` won't be caught by webNavigation.